# Why does this list comprehension throw an out of range error

Tags: python

I can't quite grasp why this doesn't work:

```
seq_ls = [s0] 
seq_ls.extend([((j*seq_ls[x-1] + k)%l) for x in range(1,100,1)])
```

but this does:

```
seq_ls = [s0] 
for x in range(1,100,1):
    seq_ls.append(((j*seq_ls[x-1] + k)%l))
```

The first set of code gives me an

> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Because in the first case until the list comprehension sequence finishes `seq_ls` doesn't change its size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the []'s:

```
seq_ls.extend(((j*seq_ls[x-1] + k)%l) for x in range(1,100,1))
```

When you write:

```
seq_ls.extend([((j*seq_ls[x-1] + k)%l) for x in range(1,100,1)])
```

you are actually building a list of all the elements, and then passing that to extend. This will fail once x gets to 2, since there is no element `seq_ls[2-1]`, since it hasn't been added to `seq_ls` yet.

However, if you remove the brackets, then the argument to extend becomes a generator expression. In this case, the individual elements aren't all constructed in advance, but only one at a time, as they are passed to `seq_ls.extend`. In this case, your indexing *should* work, since each `x-1`th element will have been added already.

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the evaluation order, before the `extend` call, your list comprehension is evaluated:

```
[((j*seq_ls[x-1] + k)%l) for x in range(1,100,1)]
```

this obviously can't work, because at that point there is only `seq_ls[0]`.

Your second code sample is iterative: each successor element is calculated after not only *calculating* the previous one, but also *adding it to the list*.

Answer (score -1):

The list comprehension is eager evaluation, You can use generator expression to replace it. The generator expression is lazy evaluation.